# Obtener Dias de division entera

Tags: php, html, array, formularios

Actualmente estoy desde un formulario, obteniendo los dias de lunes a domingo de la siguiente forma:

```html
     <td><dl class="dropdown"> 
          <dt>
         <a href="#">
           <span class="hida">Dias</span>    
           <p class="multiSel"></p>  
         </a>
         </dt>
       
         <dd>
             <div class="mutliSelect">
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="64" />Lunes</li>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="32" />Martes</li>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="16" />Miercoles</li>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="8" />Jueves</li>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="4" />Viernes</li>
                     <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="2" />Sabado</li>
         <li>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="1" />Domingo</li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
         </dd>
     </dl></td>
```

Los numeros son  porque para insertar en mi tabla mysql, debo insertar un solo valor, y no quiero insertar, lunes, martes, miercoles, etc.
Entonces estoy insertando el total que lo obtengo asi en el POST

```
 //Saber la suma de los dias 
$dias = $_POST['dias'];  
$suma = 0; 
if(count($dias) > 0){   

foreach($dias as $valor){  

$suma_d += $valor;  

} 

}
```

El tema es que ahora necesito presentar mediante html que dias eligio y debo convertir el numero a los dias, la formula seria por ejemplo
si elijo, martes, miercoles y viernes

32 + 16 + 4 = 52
52 cabe en 64 = No - Entonces no es Lunes
52 cabe en 32 = Si - Entonces es Martes y sigo
52 - 32 * 1 = 20 
20 cabe en 16 = Si- Entonces es Miercoles y sigo
20 - 16*1 = 4
4 cabe en 8 = No entonces no es Jueves
4 cabe en 4 ) Si - Entonces es viernes y sigo
0 no puedo seguir.
Los dias son Martes, Miercoles y viernes.

Asi es como debo hacerlo pero no se como presentarlo en PHP.

Comment: Intente hacerlo, pero no supe como enviar X días elegidos y generar X cantidad de valores a insertar en la base de datos, sin asociar una cantidad determinadas de variables =/ 
entonces use esta opcion para insertar solo 1 valor =/

Comment: solo guardas los seleccionados sabes que 1=lunes , 2=martes 3= miercoles... , los demas por deduccion son todos aquellos que no se entuentren en la lista

Comment: si, eso esta claro, pero envio desde el formulario <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="2" <input type="checkbox" name="dias[]" value="3" que serian martes y miercoles. Lo que no se es como obtenerlos en el post para insertarlos
porque se supone que obtendria
$dia[] = $_POST[dia];
Como digo, me envio 2 dias? o 3 dias? o 4 ? 
tendria que hacer
$dia[1] = $_Post[dia]
$dia[2] = $_POST[dia] 
etc, como hago eso si no se cuantos dias eligio ?

Comment: $_POST[dia]; recibira un arreglo si por lo menos seleciona uno , solo debes recorrer las posiciones key es el orden en que el usuario selecciono, el value el dia

Comment: =/ y como hago eso?
se que recibira algo el POST pero como inserto luego en la base de datos? como configuro el codigo para insertar X cantidad si no se cuantos son?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin modificar mucho tu código, lo que podrías hacer es convertir `$suma_d` en binario usando la función [decbin](http://php.net/manual/es/function.decbin.php), y luego sumarle 10000000 para asegurarte de tener siempre 8 cifras, de las cuales la primera es sólo relleno.

```
<?php

// lunes $suma_d = 64
$binario = decbin($suma_d)+10000000;  // 11000000

// martes, miércoles y viernes $suma_d = 52
$binario = decbin($suma_d)+10000000;  // 10110100
```

Guardas ese binario en tu base de datos, y a la hora de recuperarlo puedes recorrer el valor tratándolo como string. En PHP los strings se comportan como arrays en el sentido que puedes elegir el enésimo caracter usando `$texto[$n]`, de manera que si haces:

```
$martes = (strval($binario))[2];
```

tendrás en `$martes` un 1 o un 0. Y con eso ya puedes reconstruir la selección.

**EDIT**

Cuando quieras recuperar los días, puedes hacer

```
$resultado=10110100; // esto lo obtienes de la BBDD
$res_str=strval($resultado);

$dias=['Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado','Domingo'];

for($i=1; $i<=7; $i++) {
  if($res_str[$i]) {
    echo $dias[$i-1].'<br>';
  }

}
```

Comment: es decir si tengo que mostrar por echo los dias seleccionados tendria que ser
    if($dia[1] = (strval($binario))[1]) {
       echo "Lunes";
     } elseif ($dia[2]=(strval($binario))[2]) {
         echo " martes " ;
    }

asi ?

Comment: Más bien recorrería el binario con un `for`. Revisa la edición a la respuesta

Comment: Entiendo, sin embargo debo mostrar los dias que estan seleccionados en una tabla html. Es decir si los dias que fueron seleccionados son martes, miercoles y jueves = 56. Tengo una tabla html que muestra la informacion y deberia decir
Dias A utilizar
Mar, Mie, Jue...

Por eso pensaba en algo como lo que te mostre =/

Comment: A cabo de entender el codigo que indicaste, gracias! lo estoy probando

Comment: Funciona perfecto lo que me sugeriste, sin embargo necesito concatenar los resultados para ponerlos solo en una "celda" por asi decirlo, ya que actualmente me aparecen los dias separados por columna =/

Comment: Lo resolvi de la siguiente forma: y con tu ayuda quedo funcionando! mil gracias!

    $resultado = decbin($mostrar['cp_dias'])+10000000;  // 11000000
    $res_str=strval($resultado);
    $dias=['Lun','Mar','Mie','Jue','Vie','Sab','Dom'];
    for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++) {
    if($res_str[$i]) {
     $valor_d.=$dias[$i-1].",";
     }
    } 
    $valor=substr($valor_d,0,-1);//Elimino coma anterior
    echo '<td>'.$valor.'</td>';

Comment: esta funcionando pero me arroja unos mensajes de error

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 8 in /var/www/autocall/set_db.php on line 492

Notice: Undefined variable: valor in /var/www/autocall/set_db.php on line 496

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 8 in /var/www/autocall/set_db.php on line 492

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 8 in /var/www/autocall/set_db.php on line 492

Cual es el problema?

Comment: Ooops, el for debe llegar hasta 7, no hasta 8

Comment: @Lusagsilva, por favor, si esta respuesta solucionó tu inquietud, marca la respuesta como [respuesta aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) o [vota positivamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) a esta respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Se soluciono! muchas gracias!

Comment: perdona la ignorancia pero no se donde valorar la respuesta o marcar aceptada =/

Comment: ya lo hice, gracias =)